# Writing a unit test to test if a command CanExecute() which depends on whether a ViewModel is Dirty

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm

The test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public async Task SaveCommandCorrectlyEnabled()
        {
            await _testViewModel.Initialise();
            var saveCommandIsEnabled = _testViewModel.SaveCommand.CanExecute
                (_testViewModel.SecondViewModelViewModel.Dirty);
            _testViewModel.SecondViewModelViewModel.TestNo = "999";
            Assert.AreEqual(true, saveCommandIsEnabled);

        }
```

Relevant code in ViewModel:

```
public ICommand SaveCommand { get; }
private bool CanSave=> SecondViewModelViewModel?.Dirty ?? false;
```

(In the constructor:)

```
SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save).ObservesCanExecute(() => CanSave);
```

SecondViewModel is being instantiated by `Initiliase()`. Even when `Dirty = true`, `saveCommand = false`. Why is this?

Comment: 1. The `CanExecute` argument looks weird/useless to me. 2. You get the value for `saveCommandEnabled` **before** you assign a value to the `TestNo` property which - hopefully, as we can not see that code - set the `Dirty` property to `true`